# Can HttpMetric set time directly without calling start/stop?

Tags: firebase-performance

For a cleaner code style, I just want to know is there a way to set HttpMetric time attribute directly not using `start()` or `stop()`.
Because I can get the time directly, and don't want to add any `start/stop` listener for it.
I've found HttpMetric has a `putAttribute` method, so I guess it is possible to set the time directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the documentation https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/get-started-android#manual-network, this is not possible. Using start() and stop() is the recommended way of using HTTPMetric.